# I need help understanding RxJx subscribe syntax

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

This is what I am doing now, and I wonder if there is a better way

```
this.dataService.subscribe(
    data => this.data = data,
    error => alert('Something went wrong'),
    () => this.doSomethingOnCompletion());
```

If I'm not catching data, however, I might just alter the first of the three functions:

```
() => null,
```

The [documentation for rxjs 4.x](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md) doesn't answer this question well enough for me. [Version 5.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subscription.md) explains even less.

So, what is the verdict? Is the following wrong when I need to do nothing more than trigger something to happen?

```
this.dataService.subscribe(
    () => null,
    error => alert('Boom.'),
    () => this.doSomethingOnCompletion());
```

If I didn't need to do something on completion, I'd just leave that part out. What if I only wanted to check for errors and nothing else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RxJS 4 if you only need `errors` then you can use the `subscribeOnError` method which handles only the errors.

You can use the subscribe method as well, but you just need to pass a null value for the handlers you don't want, you don't have to pass your own noop.

```
this.dataService.subscribe(
    null,
    error => alert('Something went wrong'));
```

RxJS 5 you can pass a so-called [`PartialObserver`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observer.ts):

```
this.dataService.subscribe({
  error: error => alert('Boom.'), 
  complete: () => this.doSomethingOnCompletion()
})
```

Comment: This, the PartialObserver, is exactly what I was looking for, although, to be honest, I don't understand from looking at the source code how Observer.ts will understand which key:value pairs go to which interface. I will play around with this this morning. :)

Comment: So it looks like the way I've been doing things is just fine. It's just like calling a function with optional arguments. If you want the second or third optional arguments, you have to pass a null to the first ones.

In terms of Angular 2, the Observable we get back from the http service isn't typical, and so it doesn't really take the PartialObserver way on its own. 

Thanks for the guidance!